# Using dictionary to change the arguments of a variable

Tags: python, dictionary, timedelta

I'm trying to use a dictionary to change the value that is inserted in the arguments of a function.

```
horizon = 'YEARS'

Dict1 = {'YEARS':'weeks = 52*x','WEEKS':'weeks = x','DAYS':'days = x','HOURS': 'hours = x'} 

dummy = pd.to_datetime(pd.datetime.now())

dummy2 = [dummy - timedelta(weeks=x) for x in range(1,5)]

dummy3 = [dummy - timedelta((Dict1[horizon])) for x in range(1,5)]
```

In this case the `dummy2` variable works but the `dummy3` variable won't as `Dict1[horizon][0]` would give a string.

Can I implement this in any other way?

Comment: I have imported timedelta from datetime. One way to do this is to use IF-ELSE loops but i would like to avoid that. Any other approach is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, making use of dictionary unpacking and a lambda function.

```
Dict1 = {'YEARS': lambda a: {'weeks': 52 * a}, ...

... timedelta(**Dict1[horizon](x)) ...
```

**How does this work?**

Well, first `Dict1['YEARS']` is returning a function: `lambda a: {'weeks': 52 * a}`. Which when called with for example `2` will return a one element dictionary: {'weeks': 104}. Then, this is unpacked by the double star (**) when passed to the function, turning `timedelta(**{'weeks': 104})` into `timedelta(weeks=104)`. Exactly as we wanted.